# On Linux Mint 18, how can I update WINE to 1.9.x?

Tags: linux-mint, wine

I'm using WINE for a few applications. Recently, I've needed to update the WINE package that was installed via the software manager. The version I have is `1.6.2`, while the latest dev release, according to WineHQ, is `1.9.17`. I can download and extract the tarball, but I get this whenever I try to configure it (using `--enable-win64` and `--without-freetype` options):

```
configure: libxcursor 64-bit development files not found, the Xcursor extension won't be supported.
configure: libxi 64-bit development files not found, the Xinput extension won't be supported.
configure: libxrandr 64-bit development files not found, XRandr won't be supported.
configure: libxinerama 64-bit development files not found, multi-monitor setups won't be supported.
configure: libxcomposite 64-bit development files not found, Xcomposite won't be supported.
configure: libOSMesa 64-bit development files not found (or too old), OpenGL rendering in bitmaps won't be supported.
configure: OpenCL 64-bit development files not found, OpenCL won't be supported.
configure: pcap 64-bit development files not found, wpcap won't be supported.
configure: libdbus 64-bit development files not found, no dynamic device support.
configure: lib(n)curses 64-bit development files not found, curses won't be supported.
configure: libsane 64-bit development files not found, scanners won't be supported.
configure: libv4l 64-bit development files not found.
configure: libgphoto2 64-bit development files not found, digital cameras won't be supported.
configure: libgphoto2_port 64-bit development files not found, digital cameras won't be auto-detected.
configure: liblcms2 64-bit development files not found, Color Management won't be supported.
configure: libz 64-bit development files not found, data compression won't be supported.
configure: libpulse 64-bit development files not found or too old, Pulse won't be supported.
configure: gstreamer-1.0 base plugins 64-bit development files not found, gstreamer support disabled
configure: OSS sound system found but too old (OSSv4 needed), OSS won't be supported.
configure: libcapi20 64-bit development files not found, ISDN won't be supported.
configure: libcups 64-bit development files not found, CUPS won't be supported.
configure: fontconfig 64-bit development files not found, fontconfig won't be supported.
configure: libgsm 64-bit development files not found, gsm 06.10 codec won't be supported.
configure: libtiff 64-bit development files not found, TIFF won't be supported.
configure: libmpg123 64-bit development files not found (or too old), mp3 codec won't be supported.
configure: libopenal 64-bit development files not found (or too old), OpenAL won't be supported
configure: openal-soft 64-bit development files not found (or too old), XAudio2 won't be supported
configure: libldap (OpenLDAP) 64-bit development files not found, LDAP won't be supported.

configure: WARNING: libxrender 64-bit development files not found, XRender won't be supported.

configure: WARNING: libxml2 64-bit development files not found (or too old), XML won't be supported.

configure: WARNING: libxslt 64-bit development files not found, xslt won't be supported.

configure: WARNING: libgnutls 64-bit development files not found, no schannel support.

configure: WARNING: libjpeg 64-bit development files not found, JPEG won't be supported.

configure: WARNING: libpng 64-bit development files not found, PNG won't be supported.

configure: WARNING: No sound system was found. Windows applications will be silent.
```

Do I need to install additional packages (the ones not found, for example) in order to upgrade to a new version of WINE? Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: (1) those are only warnings, `wine` should work (although I suspect there were errors after that).  (2) You're not upgrading `wine` you're installing a new `wine` by compiling it from source. (3)  Yes, you definitely want the `*-dev` packages to compile `wine` from source. (4) You probably should post the full command you executed (i suspect it was: `./configure --enable-win64 --without-freetype` but someone may read that wrong)

Comment: Is there a way to update my preexisting WINE installation (the one installed via the software manager)?

Comment: You could use `wine 1.8` from [ubuntu-wine ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), they didn't create a 1.9 release yet though.  Mint uses ubnutu repositories, so it should work (and work without breaking anything which is also quite important)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
wine --version
```